# Appjar: How can I change windows using buttons?

Tags: python

How can I change windows using buttons?

```
from appJar import gui


def press(btn):

def revision(rvs):
    app = gui("Revision page", "500x200")
    app.setBg("green")
    app.setFont(18)
    app.addLabel("title2", "Please select a topic you would like to rveise")
    app.go()

def menu():
    app = gui("Menu", "500x200")
    app.setBg("green")
    app.setFont(18)
    app.addLabel("title1", "Menu")
    app.addButtons(["Revision", "Quiz", "Progress"], press)
    app.go()
menu()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run two instances of appJar, instead, you need to create subWindows: http://appjar.info/pythonSubWindows/

So, using your current code:

```
from appJar import gui 

def press(btn):
    if btn == "Revision":
        app.showSubWindow("Revision page")


app = gui("Menu", "500x200")
app.setBg("green")
app.setFont(18)
app.addLabel("title1", "Menu")
app.addButtons(["Revision", "Quiz", "Progress"], press)

app.startSubWindow("Revision page", "500x200")
app.setBg("green")
app.setFont(18)
app.addLabel("title2", "Please select a topic you would like to rveise")
app.stopSubWindow()

app.go()
```

---

It's easier to visualise if you use contextManagers:

```
from appJar import gui

def press(btn):
    app.showSubWindow(btn + " page")

with gui("Menu", "500x200") as app:
    app.setBg("green")
    app.setFont(18)
    app.addLabel("title1", "Menu")
    app.addButtons(["Revision", "Quiz", "Progress"], press)

    with app.subWindow("Revision page", size="500x200"):
        app.addLabel("revTitle", "Please select a topic you would like to rveise")

    with app.subWindow("Quiz page", size="500x200"):
        app.addLabel("quizTitle", "Quiz Page")

    with app.subWindow("Progress page", size="500x200"):
        app.addLabel("progTitle", "Check Progress")
```

---

And, in the latest release, a lot of the properties can be set as parameters and there are new functions for adding widgets:

```
from appJar import gui

def press(btn):
    app.showSubWindow(btn + " page")

with gui("Menu", "500x200", bg='green', font={'size':18}) as app:
    app.label("Menu")
    app.buttons(["Revision", "Quiz", "Progress"], press)

    with app.subWindow("Revision page", size="500x200", bg='red'):
        app.label("Please select a topic you would like to rveise")

    with app.subWindow("Quiz page", size="500x200", bg='blue'):
        app.label("Quiz Page")

    with app.subWindow("Progress page", size="500x200", bg='orange'):
        app.label("Check Progress")
```